# a simple visualization when write excel with python

Tags: python-3.x, excel

this might be a stupid question but I need some insight

I currently already create an excel file with openpyxl. But now, I would like to add a visualization on the 4th column

I want to create a visual for two points like shown below
[image]

Pretty much a scale that shows the two points between actual vs reference. I don't know what to call this chart, but I found something really similar with sparkline (which is not what I am looking for).

Does anyone have any suggestion on what tool to use that can create this type of visualization when writing the file with python?

thank you